# the effect of yield an print in generator?

Tags: python, generator

code1

```
import os
def walk_dir(dirname):
        for d in os.listdir(dirname):
                path = os.path.join(dirname, d)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        for f in walk_dir(path):
                           print f
                else:
                        yield path

for file in walk_dir("/tmp"):
  print  file
```

code2

```
import os
def walk_dir(dirname):
        for d in os.listdir(dirname):
                path = os.path.join(dirname, d)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        for f in walk_dir(path):
                           yield f
                else:
                        yield path

for file in walk_dir("/tmp"):
  print  file
```

When code1  and code2 run, it get the same output,i want to know why?
why `yield f` and `print f`  can get the same effect?

as Vanesa Milagros Fernandez say:print f # -----> You print f but don't runed it.
let's make more discussion.
code3

```
import os
def walk_dir(dirname):
        for d in os.listdir(dirname):
                path = os.path.join(dirname, d)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        for f in walk_dir(path):
                           pass
                else:
                        yield path

for file in walk_dir("/tmp"):
  print  file
```

why code3 can not get right answer?  if you add :print f in for loop`for f in walk_dir(path)`,and `print f` will not be run,why can't i subtitue for pass?
consider the problem in function,revise code2 into code4,
code4

```
import os
def walk_dir(dirname):
        for d in os.listdir(dirname):
                path = os.path.join(dirname, d)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        walk_dir(path)                      
                else:
                        print  path
```

i change it into a simple function,when run walk_dir("/tmp"),i get proper output.

let's revise code4 into code5
code5

```
import os
def walk_dir(dirname):
        for d in os.listdir(dirname):
                path = os.path.join(dirname, d)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        walk_dir(path)                      
                else:
                        yield  path

for file in walk_dir("/tmp"):
  print  file
```

code5 can't get right amswer.
i feel there is something confused me,can you make me clear?

Answer (score 3):

They don't do the same thing.  `yield` sends a value back to the caller.  `print` writes stuff to `sys.stdout`.

In this case however, when the caller gets a value back from `yield`, it just prints it, so the end result is the same ...

Answer (score 2):

In the latter program, everything you `yield` is printed in the loop at the end. Try changing the last line to

```
print("Yielded: " + file)
```

to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

In both codes you are printing f. In the first you print f in the function, in the second code you print f in the last loop.

See comments...

code 1

```
import os
def walk_dir(dirname):
        for d in os.listdir(dirname):
                path = os.path.join(dirname, d)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        for f in walk_dir(path):
                           print f # -----> You print f but don't runed it
                else:
                        yield path

for file in walk_dir("/tmp"):
  print  file
```

code 2

```
import os
def walk_dir(dirname):
        for d in os.listdir(dirname):
                path = os.path.join(dirname, d)
                if os.path.isdir(path):
                        for f in walk_dir(path):
                           yield f # --> You don't print f but return f to the loop
                else:
                        yield path

for file in walk_dir("/tmp"):
  print  file
```